# Does the Application class in Prism Library store data persistently?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am currently using the Prism Library to build a Xamarin.Forms application. Prism provides developers with an interface 'IApplicationStore'  that exposes properties. I implement the interface in my application. I was wondering does the Properties dictionary exposed in the interface store data persistently to a user's device or is this data only available whilst the application is open  or in the background? The documentation on the Prism Library Github page doesn't really specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source code of ApplicationStore on Prism repo on Github:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Prism.AppModel
{
    public class ApplicationStore : IApplicationStore
    {
        public IDictionary<string, object> Properties
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Properties; }
        }

        public Task SavePropertiesAsync() =>
            Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }
}
```

So it's just a wrapper around Xamarin.Forms application properties.
If you want to persist the properties, just call SavePropertiesAsync() and it should be fine:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.savepropertiesasync?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That definitely makes it clear.

Comment: @JeluMiah, could you mark the question as answered? thanks!